# React App crashes when running the production build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, netlify

I can run my react-app (with the create-react-app boilerplate) perfectly fine with the local dev-server, but when I compile it using `npm run build` and then run it with a server (I tried netlify and local http-server), I do only get this error and the page does not load:

```
classCallCheck.js:1 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.a (classCallCheck.js:1)
    at e (Object.js:6)
    at e (Object.js:6)
    at e (Object.js:6)
    at e (Object.js:6)
    at e (Object.js:6)
    at e (Object.js:6)
    at e (Object.js:6)
    at e (Object.js:6)
    at e (Object.js:6)
```

The file Object.js is placed under src/Model/Objects/Object.js.

GitHub: https://github.com/Tracer1337/DynaSys
Deployed on Netlify: https://youthful-mestorf-9e0ba8.netlify.com/

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Do you get this error while building or when trying to run the server?

Comment: @ErnestoStifano When running the build in the browser

Comment: This is usually caused by a deep recursion. Your app is loading and started, but your browser gives up after finding some code that calls too many functions without stopping. Use your browser's profiler to see which functions are called and/or use the debugger to set breakpoints and step through the calls until it breaks to find out where you get stuck.

Comment: @rickdenhaan That's the point. I don't know how to debug this because this only occurs when the react-app is built but not in dev-mode (=> npm start)

Comment: Your app builds perfectly in debian. Are you in Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was an interesting one to debug. It seems like you have created a class called `Object`, which is a protected word in JavaScript.

You can figure out what is causing the issue by clicking on the source on the right hand side of the error. This will open the corresponding file that is causing the error (`create-react-app` provides source maps by default, so debugging even in production is not an issue).

I solved the issue by renaming the `Object` class to `InternalObject`, now everything runs fine even in production mode!

As to why it does work in development mode with that protected name, I have no clue though. Maybe someone else has an idea?

Comment: @omnidan maybe dev mode doesn't have `use strict`, not sure though

Comment: @mqklin I was thinking about that, but that should not cause an infinite loop and the `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error

Answer (score 4):

Leaving this here for future reference. My React app was crashing on only one specific screen on the production build, but not in the dev environment.

Using `adb logcat *:E` I managed to track it down to an erroneous import very likely caused by vscode's intellisense importing a function from the wrong place.

Instead of doing `import { useState } from "react"`, I was importing the `useState()` function from `"react/cjs/react.development"`. Interestingly enough, the `useState()` from the wrong file actually worked just fine in the development build (the name of the file might be a hint as to the reason why).