# React Project Error (Max Call Stack) After Deploying

Tags: reactjs, web, deployment, state, callstack

I hosted my small react project on *Netlify*, *Surge* and *Roast*. However, it's giving me blank screen when I load it. It gives following error on console.

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
> at Object.a (classCallCheck.js:1)
> at new a (main.f994feda.chunk.js:1)
> at new a (main.f994feda.chunk.js:1)
> at new a (main.f994feda.chunk.js:1)
> at new a (main.f994feda.chunk.js:1)
> at new a (main.f994feda.chunk.js:1)
> at new a (main.f994feda.chunk.js:1)
> at new a (main.f994feda.chunk.js:1)
> at new a (main.f994feda.chunk.js:1)
> at new a (main.f994feda.chunk.js:1)

However, my app is working perfectly if I use `yarn start` or `npm start`.

**Update:** App Works If I remove this component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import './static_half_style.css'

export default class Array extends React.Component{
    displayElements=()=>
    this.props.elements.map(element=>{
        var text;
        if(this.props.show){
            text=<h2>{element.text}</h2>
        }else{
            text=<h2></h2>
        } 
    return(<div style={ {height :`${parseInt(element.text)*(this.props.show?100:window.screen.height/360)}px`,backgroundColor:`${element.color}`}}
        className='single-item'>
         {text}
        </div>)
        })
    render(){
        return(
            <div className='dynamic-half'>
                {this.displayElements()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue, and found a working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60739452/react-app-crashes-when-running-the-production-build).

In my case, the issue was a result of having created a custom `Object` class (as outlined in the thread above). I would hazard a guess that you're experiencing the same issue because you've defined a custom `Array` class.

Try renaming your `Array` class and deploying again.